# Python for-loop in the middle of a statement

Tags: python

I come from a C-like language background, so the code below looks pretty confusing to me:

```
#source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4n7NPk5lwbI (timestamp 3:39)
def rotation(t):
    """ Return list of rotations of input string t"""
    tt = t * 2       #why??, and is this concatenation?
    return [ tt[i:i+len(t)] for i in xrange(0, len(t)) ] #what is this for loop return/splice?
```

This should produce for a given input, say `t = "abc$"`:

```
[[abc$], [bc$a], [c$ab], [$abc]]
```

Or some permutation of the above output. Could someone explain what this code is doing? Including an example of input/output. I got a vague idea when typing this out, but it would help me to hear from someone that knows python.

Comment: The function is rotating the string in anti-clockwise

Comment: Read through [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rotation(t):
    """ Return list of rotations of input string t"""
    tt = t * 2       #why??, and is this concatenation?
    return [ tt[i:i+len(t)] for i in xrange(0, len(t))]
```

`tt = t * 2` - why is this concatenation needed? So that you can easily choose substring using from index and to index.

`abc$` would become `abc$abc$`

`[ tt[i:i+len(t)] for i in xrange(0, len(t))]` - This is a list comprehension. It's like a one liner for loop. You are looping and also building a list of different rotations of the string i.e you are using sliding window to get different rotations

And the final output is `['abc$', 'bc$a', 'c$ab', '$abc']`. It's not a nested list

Comment: Is this the only occurence where a `for` keyword appears like that?

Comment: Can you elaborate @SilverFlash?

Comment: I assumed that for loop keyword only appeared in the normal way. Don't worry about it, this one is off-topic from the original question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a normal `for` lop, rather it is a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

In short, a list comprehension iterates over an iterable, and builds a new list from operations over each element.

Python supports operator overloading, so the multiplication line is simply the implementation of multiplication on Python sequences, which is generally to repeat it:

```
>>> [1, 2] * 2
[1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> "12" * 2
'1212'
```

Essentially, this code duplicates the sequence, then creates a sliding window over the new double-length sequence.

Note that `collections.deque` has a method for rotation, so a good solution for this task is simply:

```
def rotation(t):
  current = collections.deque(t)
  yield list(current)
  for _ in range(len(current)):
    current.rotate(1)
    yield list(current)
```

(You could of course use `"".join()` for string results.)

Answer (score 1):

```
def rotation(t):
    tt = t * 2  # 2 copies of the string t, yes this is concatenation

    # The list comprehension you questioned is basically equivalent to this
    result = []
    for i in xrange(0, len(t)):
        result.append(tt[i:i+len(t)])  # the substring from i (inclusive) to i+len(t) (exclusive)
    return result
```